# Periodically polling consumer metrics with Reactor Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, metrics, reactor

We have a Spring Boot project using Reactor Kafka and a `KafkaReceiver` for consuming and we would like to collect and emit the underlying consumer metrics. It looks like we could leverage `KafkaReceiver.doOnConsumer()` with something like this:

```
receiver.doOnConsumer(Consumer::metrics)
                .flatMapIterable(Map::entrySet)
                .map(m -> Tuples.of(m.getKey(), m.getValue()))
```

If this is the best approach I'm not sure what the best way to do this periodically would be.

I notice there's also a version of the `KafkaReceiver.create()` factory method that takes a custom `ConsumerFactory`, maybe there's some way to use this to register the underlying Kafka consumer with Micrometer at creation time? I'm new to Spring Boot and relatively new to Kafka Reactor so I'm not totally sure.

Here's a snippet of my code so far for more context:

```
KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions(Collections.singleton(topic)).commitInterval(Duration.ZERO))
    .receive()
    .groupBy(m -> m.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
    .flatMap(partitionFlux -> partitionFlux.publishOn(this.scheduler)
        .map(r -> processEvent(partitionFlux.key(), r))
        .concatMap(this::commit))
    .doOnCancel(this::close)
    .doOnError(error -> LOG.error("An error was encountered", error))
    .blockLast();
```

If taking the `doOnConsumer()` approach makes sense we could possibly hook into `doOnNext()` but then we'd be collecting and emitting metrics for every event, which is too much, would be better if we could stagger and batch.

Any suggestions or tips appreciated, thanks.